# Jquery colpick color picker plugin not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, color-picker

I searched for a jquery color picker plugin and found the Colpick plugin from [this](http://colpick.com/plugin) link.

When I tried to implement it, I have no idea why it doesn't work.

I've tried implementing it on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eF5PZ/), but still it doesn't work.

Am I missing something or there's something wrong in how I implement it, that's why it doesn't work?

```
$('#picker').colpick({
    layout:'hex',
    submit:0,
    colorScheme:'dark',
    onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el,bySetColor) {
        $(el).css('border-color','#'+hex);
        // Fill the text box just if the color was set using the picker, and not the colpickSetColor function.
        if(!bySetColor) $(el).val(hex);
    }
    }).keyup(function(){
        $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);


    });
```

Comment: Did you add the Colpick's js and css files and reference them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to your project on jsfiddle you called plugin before it defined.i correct your code and it works fine. see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eF5PZ/1/)

i just moved your code:

```
$('#picker').colpick({
    layout:'hex',
    submit:0,
    colorScheme:'dark',
    onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el,bySetColor) {
    $(el).css('border-color','#'+hex);
    // Fill the text box just if the color was set using the picker, and not the colpickSetColor function.
    if(!bySetColor) $(el).val(hex);
}
}).keyup(function(){
    $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);
});
```

at the end of java scripts

Comment: how do you make it run on page load so that it reads the color in the field and display it right away?